# Будет ли сайт загружаться быстрее, если я уберу некий css элемент с помощью Stylish ?

Tags: css

Для Youtube я убрала секцию неконструктивных (как это обычно бывает) комментариев этим кодом в расширении *Stylish* :

```
ytd-item-section-renderer {
    display: None;
}
```

Мне это кажется или такой метод на самом деле ускоряет загрузку страницы ?

Comment: Возможно. Измерьте загрузкой разных страниц с разных компьютеров. Stack Overflow вам в этом вопросе не сможет помочь.

Comment: Нет. Сначала грузится страница, потом внедряются стили от стайлишь, в итоге будут все стадии включая прорисовку элементов и только потом вы их уберете. Если эти элементы влияют на ререндер страницы - то возможно это поможет с использованием страницы, но не при загрузке страницы.

Comment: ...что совершенно не учитывает тот факт, что YouTube загружает комментарии асинхронно, а не как часть основной страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет это никак не ускорит загрузку, это просто установка стиля в "не отображать". Сам же контент грузится так же как и раньше грузился.

Кроме того stylish срабатывает уже после загрузки страницы.

С другой стороны на отображение тоже уходят ресурсы компьютера, но это настолько мало, конечно я замеры не делал но это может быть доли процента от общего времени и затрат на показ страницы.